# WinForms GridView or DataSet - Locate a row using one of the column values

Tags: c#, winforms, delphi

Trying to achieve something similar to what we have in Delphi;

1. to be able to locate a specific record in a TDataSet where you can locate a specific row using the code below
2. After locating the record, it is highlighted on the DBGrid Keep in mind the DataSet can be updated during an insert function thus the DataSet in question is not static, hence the need to locate using the
3. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

DataSet.Locate(String, Variant, [LocateOptions]);

```
//Delphi Example

Locate('StudentID', StudentIDVal, []); //The StudentID is a column in the DataSet & StudentIDVal is the lookup value
```

Comment: Assuming you have a DataGridView and you're referring to a DataTable, not a DataSet (which doesn't have Rows, even though you can create a DataReader with it), you have many options. The simpler is probably to set the DataTable as the DataSource of a BindingSource and use th BindingSource as the DataSource of your Controls. Then you can have something like: `[The BidingSource].Position = [The BidingSource].Find("StudentID", StudentIDVal);` (this moves the `Current` object) -- If `StudentID` is a PrimaryKey, you can also use the `Find()` method of the Rows collection of your DataTable

Comment: If you need `Currency` management outside the UI operations, always use a BindingSouce. Or use a BindingSouce in any case to begin with, it gives you more options in relation to data binding, filtering and it's handier in general

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jimi's answer above I was able to achieve the goal using the code below. Hope it helps someone out.

```
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectStat, ConnString);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "TableData");
        bsource.DataSource = ds.Tables["TableData"].DefaultView;

        GridData.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        GridData.DataSource = bsource;

        if (ValueToFind.Trim() != "")
        {
            int i = bsource.Find("FieldToFind", ValueToFind);
            view.Rows[i].Selected = true;
            view.FirstDisplayedCell = view.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0];
        }
```